# A department in a company where unproductive employees are transferred to instead of being fired

Tags: words, slang, business-japanese

At the job fair for college students some presenters jokingly mentioned a Japanese drama in which a company had a special department full of incompetent or inefficient employees. The company had decided to place them in that special department instead of firing them. Unfortunately I don't remember the name of the department nor the name of the TV drama.

Is there a common name for such a department? Does it really exist in real world Japanese companies?

Comment: "the name of the TV drama" >>「[ショムニ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%A0%E3%83%8B_(%E3%83%86%E3%83%AC%E3%83%93%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%83%9E)#.E3.81.82.E3.82.89.E3.81.99.E3.81.98)」？

Comment: Another one I thought of is 「[五つ星ツーリスト](http://www.ytv.co.jp/fivestar/)」, where the incompetents wound up in the 中央管理センター.  Also, I feel this question is off-topic.

Comment: We should close questions if they're actually off-topic, whether new or old.  But I think this is a combination of both an on-topic question and an off-topic question.  "What's the name of the TV show I watched?" is definitely off-topic, while "What's the name of that department?" seems to be on-topic to me.  So let's edit it to remove the off-topic bit and reopen.

Comment: @macraf:  Yep, just to show off muscles and scare away new users.

Answer (score 6):

That "department" is most commonly called 「[窓際部署]{まどぎわぶしょ}」 even though it is never an "official" department.

The word 「[窓際]{まどぎわ}」 means "by the window" and it is used because the employees placed in the above mentioned "department" have little to do except looking out the window all day every day.

Those employees, by the way, are commonly called 「窓際[族]{ぞく}」.